# re naming section to restaurant

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Our site system produces urls like this

section.php/4/1/offers-events

product/12/surprise-deal

Right now we use this to take out the .php

```
Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?).php/(.*?)$ $1.php?$2 [NC]
```

Would really like to be able to take replace 'section' with 'restaurant'. Also 'product' with 'wine'

Would this re write be possible?

Thanks Peter

Comment: So you want `/wine/12/surprise-deal` instead of `/product/12/surprise-deal`?

Comment: You've already asked this question, if you have clarifications that you need to make, edit your original question.

Comment: Yes exactly.  User anubhava was very helpful before on a previous issue.